# Regexp to match a string starting with 4 spaces followed by 5 characters and numbers

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a regexp that does the following

> match a string that starts with 4 spaces followed by at least 5 characters and then numbers

**example**

```
   ____Minera 123456789
```

So far this is my code

```
    <?php

   $x="    Minera 34";
   if(preg_match("@\w{6}+\d@i",$x))
    {echo "match found";}
   else
  {echo "no match";}
   ?>
```

but its not working for me. any ideas? thanks.

Comment: what the dashes in the above means?

Comment: ____ is the example of 4 spaces

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is not matching  begining of the string and spaces at the begining

Try this

```
 @^\s{4}+\w{6}+\s+\d@
```

Rewrite

```
    <?php

   $x="    Minera 34";
   if(preg_match("@^\s{4}+\w{6}+\s+\d@",$x))
    {echo "match found";}
   else
  {echo "no match";}
   ?>
```

> See the regex in action

https://eval.in/300405

Comment: Be aware that the `\s` pattern will match any whitespace character, including tabs and newlines, and this is probably not what the question asker wants.

Comment: `\d` matches exactly a single digit char.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pattern which requires four spaces, then requires at least five letters A-Z and/or a-z, then requires a single space, then requires one or more numbers, then try this:

```
@^ {4}([A-Za-z]{5,}) ([0-9]+)$@
```

The parentheses `()` wrap around the letters and numbers parts so you can fetch these out of a match separately, but do remove the parentheses if you don't need to extract these parts from a match.

Answer (score 0):

To match a described string (4 spaces, then at least 5 characters and numbers) you can use this regular expression:

```
/^\s{4}[a-z]{5,}\d+$/i
```

But in in your example "____Minerva 123456789", you have an extra space between characters and numbers. So if you need the a regular expression matching your example, you can use this one:

```
/^\s{4}[a-z]{5,}\s*\d+$/i
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `\s` pattern will also match newlines and tabs, and this is probably not what the question asker wants.

Comment: @Arkanon what if the op means also the tabs as spaces? It's better to ask it to the op.

Comment: If a match with a tab is required then use the explicit `\t` pattern. It makes no sense to use `\s` to match only a specific type of whitespace, and leaves the pattern open to abuse.